# Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: true

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a boolean=false variable in my Firestore collection, and when i click in the button i must then variable changes for true, my code for this is simple but the firebase dont accept. Anyone have a ideia how i change the value of my boolean variable?

```
this.firestore.doc('lunch/isBag' + this.userID).update(true);
```

this method is called when i click in the button, but returns that error:

> ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: true (found in document lunch/isBagundefined)

that it's my collection and my variable that I want to change :

[image: Firestore Collection]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore database so it'll be clear what field your are trying to update?

Comment: yes, but my variable in firestore collection is also boolean. It starts = false, but when I click it I would like it to change to =true. How do I do that?

Comment: A document is an object. You might have a field that is of type boolean. Can you share the screenshots mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: I edit the question, add the image of my firestore collection. see if it helps you to help me

Comment: Can you try out the updated answer and check if that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Data must be an object"* but your code has `update(true);` that is a boolean. Are you trying to add a field in the document? Try:

```
this.firestore.doc('lunch/' + this.userID).update({ isBag: true });
```

There's another problem with this `lunch/isBag/USER_ID` has 3 path segments that'll point to a "collection" and not a "document". So do check the path of your document once.

---

As per your database structure you have a collection "lunch" containing documents with user's UID as ID. So the document path is `lunch/USER_UID`. Now a document is an object in which you have `isBag` field. You specify an object of fields that you want to update in the `update()` method as in the answer above.

Comment: Ok, this make more sense. I try that but returns that error now:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: No document to update

Comment: @ViníciusKock that document does not exists as the error says, try `.set({ isBag: true }, {merge: true})`

Comment: i achieved. I didn't pass the right userID, i fix this problem and worked!! Thank you very much!